# Вставить символ в переменную php

Tags: php

Каким образом можно подставить знак `;` между переменной в php , которая формируется подстановкой из URI:

```
$getutm = urlencode($_GET['utm1']).'ДОБАВЛЯЮ ; так НО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ'.urlencode($_GET['utm2']);
```

Далее я хочу сформировать URL с параметрами из GET,

```
 <a href="https://example.com/?<?php printf($getutm); ?>" ></a>
```

Сейчас все ок работает, и получается :

```
https://example.com/?param1param2
```

а хочется чтобы формировалось так:  https://example.com/?param1;;param2

либо любой другой спец.символ в виде разделителя.

Comment: `...между переменной в php...` - чуть чуть смущает. что вы делаете дальше с этой переменной? для чего вам надо? опишите еще подробнее, чтобы понять вас.

Comment: @Manitikyl добавил в вопрос

Comment: параметры в GET запросе обычно разделяются амперсандом

Comment: можно амперсанд, только как реализовать?

Comment: `$getutm = urlencode('param1').'&'.urlencode('param2'); var_dump($getutm);` - ?